# failed to load builtin eslint_d for method diagnostics

Tags: lua, eslint, neovim

I encountered this problem after watching typecrafts Neovim series on Youtube. I tried with AI but it didn't work. I tried adding both `eslint_d` and `eslint-lsp` and received the same error the following error for  both of them.

**[null-ls] failed to load builtin eslint_d for method diagnostics; please check your config:**

```lua
return {
   "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim",
   config = function()
     local null_ls = require("null-ls")

     null_ls.setup({
       sources = {
         null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylua,
         null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier,
         null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.eslint_d,
       },
     })
 
      vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gf", vim.lsp.buf.format, {})
    end,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have happened due to a [recent change](https://github.com/nvimtools/none-ls.nvim/discussions/81). Try using `nvimtools/none-ls-extras.nvim` as depicted below.

```lua
return {
  "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim",
  dependencies = {
    "nvimtools/none-ls-extras.nvim",
  },
  config = function()
    local null_ls = require("null-ls")
    null_ls.setup({
      sources = {
        require("none-ls.diagnostics.eslint_d"),
        null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylua,
        null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier,
      },
    })

    vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>fm", vim.lsp.buf.format, {})
  end,
}
```